# Set Relative link in a js file to come from files source rather than domain

Tags: javascript, html, performance, hyperlink, cdn

I have a site http://www.example.com

I serve my static files from a different domain.
  eg http://www.eg.com

in my js file which is located at http://www.eg.com/js/myscript.js

I have a variable which is an image.

```
var myvar = "images/example.gif";
```

I thought the image link would be http://www.eg.com/images/example.gif but it looks like (when I view the console) it grabs the domain name so it is getting http://www.example.com/images/example.gif

Is this expected behaviour?

Is there a way around this besides hardcoding the variable to be

```
var myvar = "http://www.eg.com/images/example.gif";
```

It's not ideal to hardcode as if the domain changes I will then need to update it twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behavior because it's relative to the current URL.

If you need to use a different domain for your links/images then I would add a var to hold the host name and reference it in your JS file so you only have to change it in one place if you move the file.

So:

```
var domain = 'http://eg.com/';
var myvar = domain + "images/example.gif";
```

Or if you don't want to hardcode the domain, you could pull it from the JS source attribute:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="myjs" src="http://eg.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

Inside myscript.js:

```
var myjs = document.getElementById('myjs');
var domain = myjs.getAttribute('src').replace('myscript.js','');
var myvar = domain + "images/example.gif";
```

You could also just use the `base` tag in your header [but there are some gotcha's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag).

Comment: thanks, I have used the base tag in some cases in the past. I'll keep your other suggestions in mind for the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

All relative links are relative with respect to what you see in the address bar of the browser.

The only exception to this are images loaded in CSS (eg `background-image`s), in which case paths are relative to the CSS file.

**Edit:** Though I haven't used it personally, W3C seems to define the [`base`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag which could work for what you want

Comment: Thanks I thought I had seen it used somewhere before.  It must have been in a css file.